# Trying to set a UIButton tag within a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a custom UITableView cell class, it contains 4 buttons. I want to set the tag of these buttons in the `- (void)awakeFromNib` (the cell is setup in the interface). The tag of the button depends on the row of the cell. Is there a way to find out what row is calling the awakeFromNib?

Comment: No. The cells will be reused over and over. Each cell will be reused for different index path. And when `awakeFromNib` is called, it hasn't been assigned to a particular index path yet. The better way is to assign them in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Or if you just want to identify the buttons, just use custom cell and wire the buttons from IB.

Comment: its better you set button tag on IB.

Comment: @Shashi3456643, no he can't do it in IB, because he wants the tag to be based on the row.

Comment: (Though figuring out how a tag based on a row would be useful might take some thought....)

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm using tag based on row because in each row I have four UIButtons. Each UIButton corresponds to a user object in an array. The array order will change if a user taps a button (move button to start of array for most recently tapped). So if I want to access a user in the array when the button is tapped it's row*4 + i (where i can be 0 to 3 i.e. button 1 button 2 button3 button4 in the cell)....

Comment: OK.  I'm used to data structured so that each table row matches one array element.  If that array element is also an array (or object) in order to provide multiple things for the cell to use, so be it.  If that kind of structure was possible then the tags would only need to be 0..3.